# I am trying to update one field of a document, which is in a folder. I am using REST API and C# for achieving this. But I am getting 403: Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api

```
var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in pwd) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            SharePointOnlineCredentials credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(loginName, passWord);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
            handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

            const string url = "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}/{2}')/ListItemAllFields";
            string newurl = string.Format(url, webUrl, folderServerRelativeUrl, fileName); 
            //Creating REST url
            Uri RESTURL = new Uri(newurl);
            HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RESTURL);

            //Getting form digest
            var tFormDigest = GetFormDigest(handler, webUrl);
            tFormDigest.Wait();

            wreq.Credentials = credential;

            wreq.Method = "POST";
            wreq.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
            wreq.ContentType = "application/json; odata=verbose";
            wreq.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
            wreq.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
            wreq.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", tFormDigest.Result.FormDigestValue);

            string stringData = "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.NewDocLibraryListItem' }, 'Title': 'whatever'}";
            wreq.ContentLength = stringData.Length;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wreq.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(stringData);
            writer.Flush();

            WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

At `WebResponse wresp`, I am getting an exception 403. The URL I have been forming is `url = "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{1}/{2}')/ListItemAllFields"`.

I am having a doubt if it's correct or not.

I am also not sure about the OData type I am using `'type': 'SP.Data.NewDocLibraryListItem'`.

How this value is used, Can anyone please tell me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit

My bad, In such case also, first thing you have to do make a get query to fetch fields to and use odata.type value to know metadata to be passed.

Below would be useful for same.  Other thing I suspect is that your form digest value might not getting passed correctly, can you debug and check if it you are getting valid value when you are passing in header.

I think you are passing/using wrong method and passing unnecessary headers,

- first it would be GET method.
- Remove header wreq.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
- You don't need to pass any metadata in GET Method. So remove line which adds ContentLength in request

Below is plain example of CURL to get ListItemAllFields of folder

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/ListItemAllFields
method: GET
Headers: 
     Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    "IF-MATCH": etag or "*"
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

Ref link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Comment: I guess you haven't read the question. I want to update the field items. That's why i am passing metadata.

Comment: edited answer...but this is good use case..i will try this

Comment: I have already done that using HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RESTURL); . It was working fine. Now I am using HttpClient to update list item fields but I am getting 400 badrequest.